# How to highlight tabs in Emacs

Tags: emacs, colors, indentation

I use spaces for indentation in source code, how can I highlight/mark tabs, that are in code?

It could be red, the same as when I use `(setq-default show-trailing-whitespace t)`

Comment: @abo-abo is this a question or the answer?

Comment: The question is "is there anything wrong with `whitespace-mode`"? If there's not, it's the answer:)

Comment: @abo-abo I only want tabs not all whitespace, can I configure white-space mode to show only tabs (and in red) so it look the same as my trailing whitespace?

Comment: Yes, of course it's all configurable. Just have a look at whitespace.el or try the customize interface

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use command `toggle-highlight-tabs` from library [`highlight-chars.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight-chars.el).

Or you can turn on tab highlighting by default by adding function `hc-highlight-tabs` to `font-lock-mode-hook` in your init file:

```
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook 'hc-highlight-tabs)
```

You can turn on/off the highlighting provided by library [Highlight Chars](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/ShowWhiteSpace#HighlightChars):

- in the current buffer only (i.e., locally),
- globally whenever Font Lock mode is enabled, or
- automatically whenever a buffer is in a given major mode

Comment: It seems that it don't work with highlight-current-line.

Comment: Dunno what you mean. There is no function `highlight-current-line` in vanilla Emacs. Did you perhaps mean `hl-line-mode`? If so then yes, you will not see tab highlighting on the current line, since overlay highlighting always takes precedence over text-property highlighting and `highlight-char.el` uses font-lock, which uses text properties.

Comment: I use `highlight-current-line` mode but it work with hc-highlight-tabs when I restart Emacs.

Comment: Where is function `highlight-current-line` defined?

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightCurrentLine#toc5 but it work now. and I've used your solution.

Comment: When I do `M-: toggle-highlight-tabs`, I get ```Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable toggle-highlight-tabs)
  eval(toggle-highlight-tabs nil)
  eval-expression(toggle-highlight-tabs nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression toggle-highlight-tabs nil nil 127)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)```

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: I don't see that. Do you see it with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not then bisect your init file. If yes, contact the library maintainer with a step-by-step bug report recipe that starts from `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 9):

As a hint from @abo-abo I found that I can use whitespace-mode with this code:

```
(setq whitespace-style '(face tabs))
(whitespace-mode)
```

Comment: You can also change the colour with `(modify-face whitespace-tab nil "#F92672")` (for some reason, my theme set the foreground colour instead of background on that face, which doesn't make much sense)

Comment: And if you only want tabs in some modes, you can do e.g. `(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook (lambda () (whitespace-toggle-options 'tabs)))`

Comment: When I do `M-: whitespace-mode`, I get ```Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable whitespace-mode)
  eval(whitespace-mode nil)
  eval-expression(whitespace-mode nil nil 127)
  funcall-interactively(eval-expression whitespace-mode nil nil 127)
  call-interactively(eval-expression nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-expression)```

Comment: @unhammer If I add `(modify-face whitespace-tab nil "#F92672")` to my `~/.emacs`, I get the warning message `Symbol's value as variable is void: whitespace-tab` when starting Emacs.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye You get the error because you don't have whitespace mode installed.  If you have questions like this, please ask a proper question here or on [Emacs StackExchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is not a forum you don't ask questions in comments.

Comment: You can definitely ask questions in comments; people do it all the time. If the answer is lacking and someone asks a question because of that (I'm not say that's the case now), it can tell the person who gave the answer what is lacking in their answer and they can subsequently improve their answer according to that.

Comment: Thanks your for answer anyway, though.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye yes you can ask questions in the comments but if something is unclear in the answer just after it was answered not a few years later to someone else in the comment.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye I'm not sure if you realize but this question was answered 8 years ago and you ask a question to the person in the comment.

Comment: You're right; I did ask a question to someone else than you. Well, I disagree that you can't ask questions to people in the comments section. If they have written a suggestion that doesn't work for you, it's more relevant to ask that person about it than asking someone else.

Comment: And I'm not sure why it would matter at all that eight years have passed since you gave your answer? If the answer is still relevant, you should still be able to ask questions about it.

Comment: I see what you mean. No, I usually don't expect a reply back. Thanks for your concern.