# How to change face of whitespace-tab in whitespace-mode to red background in Emacs

Tags: emacs, colors

I have this code in my .emacs file:

```
(setq-default show-trailing-whitespace t)
(setq whitespace-style '(face tabs))
(whitespace-mode)
```

How can I change the var `whitespace-tab` so my tabs look the same as trailing whitespace (red background)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*An alternative:* do not bother with `whitespace-mode` for this.
Use library [`highlight-chars.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/highlight-chars.el) (see [your related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22019326/729907)), and just customize face `hc-tab` (`M-x customize-face hc-tab`).

Comment: How to change font face from elisp?

Comment: The same way you would for any face: `(custom-set-faces '(hc-tab ((t (:foreground "Red"))))`

Comment: Thanks it work, but I need background red and you miss one parenthesis.

Comment: And also it break `term-mode`, so I need to disable it for that mode.

Comment: It doesn't "break" anything. As I explained, font-lock highlighting is text-property based, so it is of course overruled by any overlay-based highlighting. (And FWIW, `M-x term-mode` still shows the tab highlighting, for me.)

Comment: the colors in ansi-term don't work when it's enabled. Try `(ansi-term "/bin/bash")`

Comment: I cannot try that; sorry.  But it should be easy enough for you to investigate why.  Again: the tab highlighting just uses font-lock.

Comment: The same is with ERC, I just keep the list of modes: `(setq highlight-chars-disable '(term-mode erc-mode))
(add-hook 'font-lock-mode-hook (lambda() (if (null (memql major-mode highlight-chars-disable)) (hc-highlight-tabs))))`

Comment: Yes, that is the right way to do it, as explained in the `highlight-chars.el` Commentary.  On the other hand, perhaps you can figure out why those modes interfere and work around that -- dunno.

Answer (score 1):

Found it, need to use this code:

```
(setq whitespace-style '(face tabs))
(setq tab-face (make-face 'tab-face))
(set-face-background 'tab-face "red")
(setq whitespace-tab 'tab-face)
(whitespace-mode)
```